# How to set html text into default browser from java code?

Tags: java, swt

I am using SWT's `browser.setText(html)`; to set the html into SWT `Browser`. Instead of this is there any way in java to set the same html to external default browser (IE, Chrome, Mozilla, etc)?

I want to set the html text to external default browser and open the browser with content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Program#launch(String)`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/program/Program.html#launch(java.lang.String)) to open a URL in the OSs default browser:

```
Program.launch("http://www.google.co.uk");
```

If you've got your HTML in a simple `String`, then you'll need to write it to a `File` first and then use the path to that file instead of the URL.